# Django - Access a file

Tags: django, django-staticfiles

I have a django project mysite and app named login

The web page i am opening is

> D:\mysite\templates\login\index.html

This html file needs a javascript file (in the same directory) for it to work

The js file is in

> D:\mysite\templates\login\d3.js

How to provide this path in the

```
<script src = "...\d3.js">
```

in the html file?

---

I did all this

in my urls.py

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns 
urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

in settings.py

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = ('D:/mysite/templates/login')
```

then used this in html file

```
<script src="{{static_url}}/d3.js"></script>
```

Still doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [django statics module](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/)

Then your link will be something like `<script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}/d3.js" />`

Comment: STATIC_URL needs to be in uppercase

Comment: you're also missing a comma in STATICFILES_DIRS. It should be `STATICFILES_DIRS = ('D:/mysite/templates/login', )`